# Four Square Div Rotating Center On Hover - Spinner Board

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would appreciate another pair of eyes because I'm either stuck or burned out for the evening.

All I'm trying to do is have a four square div layout inside of a containing div. That part's no big deal. My problem arises when I try to also add another div to be positioned directly in the center of these four square divs and `translate` `rotate` the center div to point to the square that has hover.

For a visual explanation, here's what I'm aiming for. Kind of almost like a spinner game board.

[image]

Here's where I'm stuck at : [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNpomG)

The problem as you'll see from the concept example is;

1. The four divs do not match the height/width of their container. So the marker does not appear in the center of the four squares.
2. The top two divs do exactly as expected and rotate the marker appropriately....*however the bottom two do not*.

Would appreciate any insight, and I'm aiming for pure HTML/CSS only by preference. Thanks!

```css
#pw-spots {
  margin: 0;
  border: green 10px solid;
}

#TL1, #TR2, #LB3, #LB4 {
  width:10em;
  height:8em;
  margin:0; 
  border:1px solid black; 
  float: left;
  display:block;
}

#TL1 {
  background-color:purple;
}

#TR2 {
  background-color:blue;  
}

#LB3 {
  background-color:wheat;
}

#LB4 {
  background-color:salmon;
}

#TL1:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: rotate(-33deg);
}
#TR2:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: rotate(33deg);
}
#LB3:hover #spinner {
  transform: rotate(99deg);
}
#LB4:hover #spinner {
  transform: rotate(-99deg);
}

#spinner {
  height:50px;
  width:10px;
  border-top:red 10px solid;
  background-color:orange;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top:-30px;
  margin-bottom:-30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pw-spots">
  <figure id="TL1">1</figure>
  <figure id="TR2">2</figure>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
  <div id="spinner" class=""></div>
  <figure id="LB3">3</figure>
  <figure id="LB4">4</figure>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure if this fixes your issue, but with the bottom two you don't have a `~` which you do have with the top 2 corners in your `css:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answers to your questions:**

> The four divs do not match the height/width of their container. So the marker does not appear in the center of the four squares.

This is because the container is a block container and so will take the full available width whereas the 4 `div` elements are floated and have a specific `width` assigned to them. You should either make the container as `display: inline-block` or set its `width: calc(20em + 4px)` (`20em` is for the 2 squares and `4px` is for the `2px` border on either side of the 2 squares).

> The top two divs do exactly as expected and rotate the marker appropriately....however the bottom two do not.

The selector is wrong. This selector - `#LB3:hover #spinner` would match a spinner element which is the ***child*** of an element whose `id` is LB3. But the spinner is not its child but rather it is a sibling. Even though it is a sibling, we cannot use `~` (general sibling combinator) because it works only for siblings that are below the reference element (in this case `#LB3`) in the DOM and not those above it. Here the spinner is above `#LB3` in the DOM and so you have to modify your structure to move it to the bottom (last element under the container).

---

**Solution:**

Below is the fixed version. I have made the changes that I had mentioned above, modified the rotation angles of the spinner, positioned it absolutely with respect to the container and then used `translate` transforms to position it.

```css
#pw-spots {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: calc(20em + 4px);
  border: green 10px solid;
}
#TL1, #TR2, #LB3, #LB4 {
  width: 10em;
  height: 8em;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
#TL1 {
  background-color: purple;
}
#TR2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#LB3 {
  background-color: wheat;
}
#LB4 {
  background-color: salmon;
}
#TL1:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
#TR2:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
#LB3:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}
#LB4:hover ~ #spinner {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(135deg);
}
#spinner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  border-top: red 10px solid;
  background-color: orange;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 2s ease; /* just for fun */
}
```

```html
<div id="pw-spots">
  <figure id="TL1">1</figure>
  <figure id="TR2">2</figure>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
  <figure id="LB3">3</figure>
  <figure id="LB4">4</figure>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
  <div id="spinner" class=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really excellent man thank you! Also thanks for the really well formed explanation. I'm still in the process of kicking the rust off my html/css since I hadn't used it in years! Cheers!